# Index corruption detected. Please retry the refactoring - indexes will be rebuilt automatically Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, refactoring

While trying to refactor in Android Studio, it is showing [this](http://prntscr.com/7be33f). What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally find the solution by reading through documentation.

Go to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart...

Android Studio Restarts.
if not restart your computer.
This one works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of some ide plugins, disable them all, invalidate caches/restart
repair ide
and then restart your OS and the issue should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

It may be occurred  due to Memory or low disk space issue.