# How to fix Index corruption detected in Android Studio when move files to another package?

Tags: android, android-studio

At the moment the following error is happening to me in Android Studio when I try to move a file to another package:

```
Error
Index corruption detected. Please retry the refactoring - indexes will be rebuilt automatically
```

Here's a gif showing this happening:

[image]

I have already tried all of these [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554661/index-corruption-detected-please-retry-the-refactoring-indexes-will-be-rebuil):

- Invalidate caches/restart;
- Restart mac;
- Build clean.

But it didn't work to me

The link that I sent suggests it can happen due to low memory, but I'm using a MacBook Pro M3 pro with 36 GB RAM + 512GB internal memory. Here are some of my Mac specifications:

**Android Studio and plugins version**

```
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570, built on February 21, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    Dart (232.10286)
    wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
    com.wakatime.intellij.plugin (14.3.11)
    org.norbye.tor.kdocformatter (1.6.2)
    com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.2(232)-20)
    com.squareup.sqldelight (2.0.1)
    com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.13)
    com.github.copilot (1.4.19.4986)
    io.flutter (78.0.2)
```

**Storage:**

[image: Storage]

**About**

[image]

**EDIT**
I deleted any relationship between Android Studio and my machine and installed it again as [this guide](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-android-studio-on-mac#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Applications%20folder,Home%20folder%20and%20remove%20them.) suggests. However, the error continues to occur.